# Visual Studio 2022 shows 1000s of Intellisense errors in my node_modules folder

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, intellisense, tsconfig

I am working in a .NET Core 3.1 project using Vue, TypeScript, and Webpack, in **Visual Studio 2022**. Intellisense is throwing 1000+ errors, but all within my `node_modules` folder:

[image: Intellisense Errors]
Per similar questions I've seen elsewhere on SO, I first confirmed that my .tsconfig is set to "Build Action: Content", and even explicitly added it to my .csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="ClientApp\tsconfig.json" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I've also tried deleting my `node_modules` folder, my `package-lock.json`, and running:

```
npm cache clean --force
npm i --legacy-peer-deps
```

This did not fix the issue. The project otherwise builds/runs perfectly. Any suggestions?

**tsconfig.json:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [ "src/*" ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost",
      "es2018"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "bin",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

Directories:

[image]

Comment: Does this can help you?(https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-cannot-find-module)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue recently. I had to make sure the 'Microsoft.TypeScript.MsBuild' assembly matched the version of 'typescript' in my packages.json file. I used NuGet package manager to downgrade the assembly to 4.6.3 to match my package.json.

Afterwards I right-clicked the 'node_modules' folder and hit 'exclude from project' ( excluding it might not of actually done anything in hindsight, it still seems to throw the occasional error from node_modules, but at least there's not 1000 of them ).

I also found that in order to get some of the types recognized, I had to do an 'npm install' while in the folder of a specific dependency.

For example react couldn't find a 'css' type, I had to go into node_modules/react/ and do 'npm install'. Then it creates node_modules/react/node_modules/css/somedef.d.ts ( more node_modules folders /sigh ). Then you can manually copy that to the proper directory ( node_modules/@types/css ) and delete the ridiculous nested folder ( node_modules/react/node_modules/css ).

Finally getting a reasonable amount of errors related to the source code I'm working on ( 0 at the moment, woo! ), hope this helps

*Edit* - it's worth noting that I ended up changing things to use the latest version of TypeScript, which helped clear up most of the remaining errors. At this point I have 0 errors, here is my package.json and tsconfig files, in-case it helps:

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "bbb",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.6",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "merge": "^2.1.1",
    "oidc-client": "^1.11.5",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.26.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "reactstrap": "^9.0.2",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^28.1.6",
    "@types/node": "^18.0.6",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "@types/reactstrap": "^8.7.2",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.5"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "css-what": "^5.0.1",
    "nth-check": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "rimraf ./build && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "cross-env CI=true react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint ./src/"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext",
      "webworker"
    ],
    "module": "ES2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es6"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Visual Studio project typescript settings:

[VS Project Typescript Settings 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cj9Ej.png)

[VS Project Typescript Settings 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OTUM.png)